# History API fallback fails on refresh

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

I have enabled the history api fallback option on my webpack dev server which is working fine when i try to directly access or refresh my `/complete` or `/incomplete` routes. However - in my switch statement i'm trying to capture all other possible url's and redirect to a 404 component.

```
<Switch>

    <Route exact path={'/'} render={()=>{
        return <Redirect to='/incomplete'/>
    }}/>

    <Route exact path={'/complete'} render={()=>{
        return ( <TodoComplete/> );
    }}/>

    <Route exact path="/incomplete" render={()=>{
        return ( <TodoIncomplete/> );
    }}/>

    <Route component={NotFound}/>

</Switch>
```

This seems to work fine and properly route to the NotFound component for a url like `http://localhost.com/undefinedroute` BUT doesn't seem to catch anything nested, for example `http://localhost.com/complete/undefinedroute`.

I instead get a console error saying my resources are trying to be loaded from an incorrect path `http://localhost.com/complete/bundle.js`

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the expected behaviour according to the doc. However, there is a big thread [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4958#issuecomment-293613721) about the behaviour, they will probably change this soon.

Answer (score 0):

In your index.html put the /bundle.js

```
<script src='/bundle.js'></script>
```